# Combining csv files with mismatched columns

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-analysis

I need to combine multiple csv files into one object (a dataframe, I assume) but they all have mismatched columns, like so:

**CSV A**

```
store_location_key | product_key | collector_key | trans_dt | sales | units | trans_key
```

**CSV B**

```
collector_key | trans_dt | store_location_key | product_key | sales | units | trans_key
```

**CSV C**

```
collector_key | trans_dt | store_location_key |product_key | sales | units | trans_id
```

On top of that, I need these to match with two additional csv files that have a matching column:

**Location CSV**

```
store_location_key | region | province | city | postal_code | banner | store_num
```

**Product CSV**

```
product_key | sku | item_name | item_description | department | category
```

The data types are all consistent, i.e., the sales column is always float, store_location_key is always int, etc. Even if I convert each csv to a dataframe first, I'm not sure that a `join` would work (except for the last two) because of the way that the columns need to match up.

Comment: Should `trans_key` and `trans_id` be the same or are they different columns?

Comment: Thanks for the reply...I'm unsure, but I think it's best to treat them as being different columns.

Comment: sample input for one or two files would be helpful and please share what you've tried so far too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To merge the first three CSV files, first read the separatly as DataFrames and then use `union`. The order and number of columns when using `union` matters, so first you need to add any missing columns to the DataFrames and then use `select` to make sure the columns are in the same order.

```
all_columns = ['collector_key', 'trans_dt', 'store_location_key', 'product_key', 'sales', 'units', 'trans_key', 'trans_id']

dfA = (spark.read.csv("a.csv", header=True)
  .withColumn(trans_id, lit(null))
  .select(all_columns))
dfB = (spark.read.csv("b.csv", header=True)
  .withColumn(trans_id, lit(null))
  .select(all_columns))
dfC = (spark.read.csv("c.csv", header=True)
  .withColumn(trans_key, lit(null))
  .select(all_columns))

df = dfA.union(dfB).union(dfC)
```

Note: If the order/number of columns were the same for the CSV files, they could easily be combined by using a single `spark.read` operation.

After merging the first three CSVs, the rest is easy. Both the location and the product CSV can be combined with the rest using `join`.

```
df_location = spark.read.csv("location.csv", header=True)
df_product = spark.read.csv("product.csv", header=True)

df2 = df.join(df_location, df.store_location_key == df_location.store_location_key)
df3 = df2.join(df_product, df2.product_key == df_product.product_key)
```