# Issues in loading multiple csv in spark with scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using **Spark2.3** with **Scala** and trying to load multiple csv files from a directory, I am getting an issue that it load files but miss some columns from them

I have following sample files

**test1.csv**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
aaa,2,3,4,5
```

**test2.csv**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
aaa,2,3,4
```

**test3.csv**

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
aaa,2,3,4,6
```

**test4.csv**

```
Col1,Col2,Col5,Col4,Col3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
aaa,2,5,4,3
```

What i want to do is load all these files into a dataframe with all the columns in 4 files but when i try to load files with following code

```
val dft = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("path/to/directory/*.csv")
```

It loads csv but misses some columns from csv.

here is the output of **dft.show()**

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col6|
+----+----+----+----+----+
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   6|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   5|   4|   3|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I want it to be like this

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
| aaa|   2|   3|   4|   5|   6|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Please guide me what is wrong with my code?
or is there any other efficient way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Some thing related to the same issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999381/combining-csv-files-with-mismatched-columns

Comment: Spark's CSV reader does not support missing columns. You have to find another way. Can you tell me how many files you have and how big they are? Also, what do you expect when the column is not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for the problem I was trying to solve,  so I thought I should share this for anyone who is trying to achieve same output.

I used Parquet to solve the merge task in different files with some common columns.

here is the code

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Exercise")
      .setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Sql Session")
      .config("spark.some.config.option", "test")
      .getOrCreate()

val filepath = sc.wholeTextFiles("path/to/MergeFiles/*.txt").keys
val list = filepath.collect().toList
var i = 1
list.foreach{ path  =>
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .option("header", "true")
    .load(path)
df.write.parquet("data/test_tbl/key="+ i)
    i +=1
}
val mergedDF = spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("data/test_tbl")

mergedDF.write.format("csv").save("target/directory/for/mergedFiles")
```

and following is the output of  `mergedDF.show()`

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col6|Col5|key|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |6   |null|2  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |4  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |3  |
|aaa |2   |3   |4   |null|5   |3  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

If each individual file is not too big, you could use `wholeTextFile` and parse your files yourself as follows:

```
val columns = (1 to 6).map("Col"+_)
val rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles("path_to_files/*")
    .map(_._2.split("\\n"))
    .flatMap(x=> { 
        // We consider the first line as the header
        val cols = x.head.split(",")
        // Then we flatten the remaining lines and shape each of them 
        // as a list of tuples (ColumnName, content).
        x.tail
            .map(_.split(","))
            .map(row => row.indices.map(i => cols(i) -> row(i))) 
    })
    .map(_.toMap)
    // Here we take the list of all the colmuns and map each of them to
    // its value if it exists, null otherwise.
    .map(map => columns.map(name => map.getOrElse(name, null) ))
    .map(Row.fromSeq _)
```

This code puts each file within a single record using `wholeTextFile` (this is why files cannot be too big), uses the first line to determine what columns are present and in which order, creates a Map that maps column names to values and convert it to a row with nulls when values are missing. Then, the data is ready to go into a dataframe:

```
val schema = StructType(
    columns.map(name => StructField(name, StringType, true))
)
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema).show()
```

Comment: thanks for replying , but  first portion gives err on "columns" in this line "map(map => columns.map(name => map.getOrElse(name, null) ))"   i.e "cmd22.sc:1: not found: value columns". Can you please tell me which columns it is referring to?

Comment: Right, I should have defined `columns` earlier ;-) I edited the answer.

Comment: thanks for the edit it solve the issue for the first portion, now the it gives error on StructField "not found: value StructField" , then i added  import statement for it and getting this error ..... "not enough arguments for method apply: (name: String, dataType: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType, nullable: Boolean, metadata: org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata)org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField in object StructField.
Unspecified value parameter dataType.
val schema = StructField("

Comment: here is the import statement i added to the 2nd portion of the code.... "import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField"

Comment: You could even put `import org.apache.spark.sql.types._` or `import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ StructType, StructField, StringType}` because you need all three. I realized that I had made another typo. I had used a StructField instead of a StructType in the schema declaration. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks bro , it is working now , but the output is not as expected . I am getting null in 6th column, values for one csv file is missing in 5th column and there are some values for 3rd and 4th columns that are null after running  this code. can you please explain the working of these lines in first part of code.... " val cols = x.head.split(",")
        x.tail
            .map(_.split(","))
            .map(row => row.indices.map(i => cols(i) -> row(i))) "

Comment: I added a few comments inside the code. In fact, null values are genarated because in some files, columns are missing. I did not know what else to put there. What would you like to see instead?